# To do a auto enter in text editor on reaching a particular character limit perline

Tags: javascript, text, editor

In a JavaScript text editor, the total characters accepted per line is 65. I want to change the number of character accepted in a line to 35 with out changing the total character length of my text editor (65).

So, if a user enters 36th character, the cursor should to go the second line although the character length per line is 65. It has to accept only 35 characters per line.

Comment: do you believe in magics ?

Answer (score 1):

One can only assume your talking about a TEXTAREA html tag, in which case your best bet would be to use a JavaScript regex replace to insert new lines you can attached this to the OnChange event.

**edit** This JS fiddle seems to work. I used the 'keyup' event instead of 'change'. http://jsfiddle.net/sUS5s/

HTML

```
<textarea id="demo" rows="5" cols="65"></textarea>
```

JS

```
$("#demo").keyup(function(event) {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(txt.replace(/([^\r\n]{35})/gm, "$1\r"));
});
```

Simple regex replace with substitution. Matching 35 consecutive NON-newline characters and replacing them with themselves plus a newline.

This will work if you continually type forward, you need something a little more complex to let you insert into previous lines etc without the new lines getting skewed.

**EDIT** Without jQuery

```
document.getElementById("demo").onkeyup = function() {
    var txt = document.getElementById("demo").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").value = txt.replace(/([^\r\n]{35})/gm, "$1\r");
};
```

Comment: Depends on if he can use jQuery or if he needs regular js

Comment: @Jeff Shaver - It's trivial/easy to convert it to straight JavaScript